# Deleting rows in linked MySQL tables and decrementing count in another table

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-delete

I am trying to create (java-based) messaging webapp. The messages are stored using MySQL using three tables:

- **'messages'**: has two columns, an id primary key ('idmessage') and the message ('message').
- **'tags'**: The user also inputs a tag associated with their message. This has two columns - the tag (which is also a primary key) and a count ('count').
- **'message_tag_link'**: Since there is a many-to-one relationship between messages and tags I have a third link table. This has two columns, both foreign keys to the messages ('fk_idmessage') and tags tables’ ids ('fk_tag').

Inserting messages into the database works fine. I use these following lines in Java:

```
pst1 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO messages(message) VALUES (?)");
pst2 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tags(tag,count) VALUES (?,1) ON     DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1");
pst3 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO message_tag_link(fk_idmessage,fk_tag) VALUES (? , ?)");
```

As can be seen ‘count’ increments in pst2 every time a duplicate tag entry is made.
I am trying to work out how to fully delete a message.  I have the `on delete cascade` description on my foreign keys in my link table’s columns but am not sure what to do next. For a given *'messageid'* I need to:

1. Delete a row in 'messages' table
2. Delete the associated row in the 'message_tag_link' table
3. Decrement the count value in the 'tags' table when a message deletion is successful, or delete this row entirely if count becomes zero.

Is it possible to do all this within MySQL using a Java `PreparedStatement`? Any pointers much appreciated. I am a total MySQL novice, so please be kind!

Comment: Is there a reason that the count is stored? You could just use the number of messages attached.

Comment: …and maybe use a `VIEW` to calculate the tag counts.

Comment: @Jim Yes. I can see a solution without the count column might work. What I am unclear about is without this column, when you delete rows from 'messages' and the link table you are potentially left with a row in the tags column that no longer corresponds to a message (i.e. scenario when count would have been zero for a tag). This is why I thought the count column would be a good & quick way of addressing this - but no idea how to use it, hence my question!

Answer (score 0):

These queries should do what you need. ? in each query should be the message id that is to be deleted

```
//Update count
UPDATE tags SET `count` = `count` - 1 WHERE tag_id IN (SELECT fk_tag FROM message_tag_link WHERE fk_idMessage = ?);
//Remove link
DELETE FROM message_tag_link WHERE fk_idmessage = ?;
DELETE FROM messages WHERE id = ?;
//Remove unused tags
DELETE FROM tags WHERE `count` = 0;
```

As you've found out however maintaining a count can be annoying. Better is to use the link itself.

```
SELECT COUNT(fk_idmessage) AS msgcount FROM message_tag_link WHERE fk_tag = ?;
```

Also you can add a CASCADE so that when messages are deleted the tag link gets deleted too (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)). Be careful with this behavior however).

This solution still leaves tags with no messages but you can remove these using the query:

```
DELETE FROM tags t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM nessage_tag_link WHERE t.tag_id = fk_tag)
```

Comment: "COUNT" is a MySQL keyword. I suggest using back ticks: UPDATE \`tags` SET \`count` = \`count` - 1... etc.

Comment: @Anton Well spotted. Have escaped the count field where appropriate.

Comment: Sweet. I went for the more verbose top one (and kept my count column) and it worked a treat.